# How to add/remove class from parent div on change radio button in vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, radio-button

I have a simple code:

```
    <div id="app">
<div class="xyz" :class="{ selectedRadio:radio_first }">
  <input type="radio" name="example" @change="radio_first = true;radio_second = false">
</div>

<div class="abc" :class="{ selectedRadio:radio_second }">
  <input type="radio" name="example" @change="radio_second = true;radio_first = false">
</div>
</div>
```

then:

```
    new Vue({

      el:"#app",
      data:{
        radio_first:false,
        radio_second:false
      }


});
```

CSS:

```
    .xyz{
  display:inline;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin-right:60px;
}

.abc{
  border:1px solid grey;
  display:inline;
  padding:20px;
}

.selectedRadio{
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

So if I check the first radio button I want to add a new class to its parent div only. and if I check second radio I need to add a class to its parent div and remove that first added class to first radios parent div.
I hope you guys understood what I want. I have tried this so far. it is working but what if I will have many radio buttons?is there any better way in vue js to solve this.
here is the codepen link:  https://codepen.io/kohalirakesh/pen/KoPMEZ
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried yet so far?

Comment: @bhojendra please check i have edited my question

Comment: Radio buttons have a value. Set the class based off the currently selected value. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qoWqxV?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert Thank you for the reply. yes, your way is better than me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this? [Example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ry38478kqp?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

You basically want to use `:class`, for example:

```
<div class="parent" :class="{'green': radio}">
  <input type="radio" v-model="radio" :value="true"/> True
</div>
<div class="parent" :class="{'red': !radio}">
  <input type="radio" v-model="radio" :value="false"/> False
</div>
```

You can read more about it in the official Vue documentation:

[Vue Documentation on Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Thank you for an answer. i have edited my question please have a look. here is codepen link : https://codepen.io/kohalirakesh/pen/KoPMEZ